# Magento join query with group by and having error

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, query

join query with customer table, and group by and having clauses not working, its show an error , filed is not found.

**The Query**

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('userid')->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')->addAttributeToSelect('profile_image')->addAttributeToSelect('specialist')->addAttributeToSelect('latitude')->addAttributeToSelect('free_consult')->addAttributeToSelect('longitude')->addAttributeToFilter('group_id',Federallawyer_Customer_Helper_Data::LAWYER);
 $collection->getSelect()->join(array('review'=>'flrating'),"e.entity_id = review.reviewed_user_id ",array('avg_rating'=>'AVG(review.avg_rating)'));
                $collection->getSelect()->group('review.reviewed_user_id');
$collection->getSelect()->having('avg_rating > ?', $min)
```

Comment: try  `$collection->getSelect()->group('review.reviewed_user_id')->having('avg_rating > {$min}' )` instead of ` $collection->getSelect()->group('review.reviewed_user_id');
$collection->getSelect()->having('avg_rating > ?', $min`

Comment: i follow your way but when i print the query using $collection->getSelect()->__toString(); its show the empty result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe because this is a calculated field, did you try this for your having clause? :

```
$collection->getSelect()->having('AVG(review.avg_rating) > ?', $min)
```

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer:

Use this code:

```
$collection->getSelect()->having('AVG(review.avg_rating) > ?', $min)
```

### Explanation:

Loading a collection with `HAVING` works fine, but if you are using this in grid context, Magento might call `getSelectCountSql()` on the collection to get a modified query to retrieve the number of results.

#### This is the method:

```
/**
 * Get SQL for get record count
 *
 * @return Varien_Db_Select
 */
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $this->_renderFilters();

    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

    $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');

    return $countSelect;
}
```

By default, it removes selected columns but unfortunately not the `HAVING` parts and so the resulting `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` query is broken.

There are some collections like the collections in `Mage_Reports` that override this method and *do* reset `HAVING`.

This is for example `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection`:

```
/**
 * Get select count sql
 *
 * @return unknown
 */
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);
    $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id)");

    return $countSelect;
}
```

I don't know why this is not included in the default implementation, but essentially it means you cannot use `HAVING` with calculated columns but must repeat the expression:

```
$collection->getSelect()->having('AVG(review.avg_rating) > ?', $min)
```