# Customer join query result getSize() issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php, query

join query with customer table getSize() count mismatch with the mysql db result.

```
Query
-----
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('endorsement'=>'flendorsement'),'e.entity_id = endorsement.to_user_id',array('total_endorsement'=>'COUNT(endorsement.endorsement_id)'));
            $collection->getSelect()->group('endorsement.to_user_id');

When i execute this query in mysql phpmyadmin, there will show the 3rows,
but  getSize() method return "2"
```

see the screen below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

`$collection->count();`

For `getSize()` the collection is not loaded. For `count()` it is.

Check the difference between `getSize()` and `count()` from here [Difference between getSize() and count() on collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4036/difference-between-getsize-and-count-on-collection/4039#4039)

Comment: the getCount() is used in custom table collection, but here i wrote the query with Magento table, that's why i am using getSize(),then i have a pagination issues also with the group by query, for your further reference i attached the screen.

Comment: getSize() does not load the collection for records that come from the data base. you need to override the method and tell it to load the collection

Comment: How can i override the getSize(),can you explain that or having any tutorial for getSize() override?

Comment: TRy this http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/01/05/magento-wrong-count-in-admin-grid-when-using-group-by-clause-overriding-lib-module/ it might help you

Comment: thanks for your support,now its working. then i have one more problem, i posted the question see the link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74278/magento-join-query-with-group-by-and-having-error?noredirect=1#comment98326_74278