# Alias field with addAttributeToFilter and HAVING

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, collection, query

I build a query with an alias field and need to include this alias field value inthe query condition.

The query:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('review'=>'flrating'),"e.entity_id = review.reviewed_user_id ",array('total_avg_rating'=>'AVG(review.avg_rating)'));
$collection->getSelect()->having('e.total_avg_rating >= ?', $min)->having('e.total_avg_rating <= ?',$max);
$collection->getSelect()->group('review.reviewed_user_id');
```

allies name is "total_avg_rating"
but it shows error: "total_avg_rating not exist".

### allies filed name result

[image]

### As per follow your mention way

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
having('e.total_avg_rating <= ?',$max)
```

to

```
having('total_avg_rating <= ?',$max)
```

since `total_avg_rating` is not a field of the main table `e` but an alias

If you still get an error, it might be because somewhere `$collection->getSize()` is called. In this case, you cannot use an alias in `having` and it has to be changed to

```
having('AVG(review.avg_rating) <= ?',$max)
```

For explanation see here: [Magento join query with group by and having error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/74278/243)

Comment: i tried total_avg_rating instead of e.total_avg_rating, but this again showing the same error

Comment: I thought so. See updated answer and link

Comment: it's working, but the result is not accurate

Comment: i read from the above link , and i check the function getSelectCountSql(), its same as my Collection.php ('app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order')file, can you explain briefly what i need do to fix the above issue

Comment: No because I don't understand your issue. You say it's working but the restults are not accurate. As far as I see, the issue from the question is resolved and now you need to work on your query to get what you really want.

Comment: i added the screen for your further reference,hope you will get idea and your suggestion will help me to resolve the problem